# Grid Search on Unsupervised Sklearn Clustering?

Tags: clustering, scikit-learn, unsupervised-learning

I am trying to use clustering algorithms in sklearn and am using Silhouette score with cosine similarity as a metric to compare different algorithms. My question is due to the varying hyperparameters of the different clustering algorithms is it possible to run some type of grid search on these algorithms in order to find the best set that optimized Silhouette score. I found this PR on Github https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/6160 but it looks like work on it died off.

Comment: IMHO, internal measures such as Silhouette are usually too unreliable to find any "best" clustering. They are also affected by normalization and the choice of distance function, and these have a major impact on the result even with Silhouette. Plus, Silhouette is $O(n^2)$.

Comment: Do you have any input on a different evaluation metric to use?